# Matrix determinant $\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have problem with this task:

Given a square matrix $A = [a_{ij}]^n_{i,j=1} \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $t \geq 0$ satisfies conditions:

1. $\forall i \neq j : a_{ij} = t,$
2. $\forall i : a_{ii} > t$.

How to prove that $\det A \neq 0$ ?

I have tried with brute force, but it isn't a good way to solve it.

Comment: if $t=0$, this is clear. otherwise divide each row by $t$ (this won't change the $\det A \neq 0$ condition), and consider what happens when you row-reduce the matrix

Comment: Hint: $A=D+tJ$ where $J$ is the all $1$ matrix and use that $B+C$ is definite positive if $B$ is positive definite and $C$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 2):

Use the matrix determinant lemma: if $A$ is an invertible matrix, then for any vectors $u$ and $v$, $$\mathrm{det}(A + uv^T) = (1+v^T A^{-1} u) \mathrm{det}(A).$$
In this case, set $A$ to be the diagonal matrix with entries $a_{ii} - t$ and $v = (t)_{k=1}^n$, $u = (1)_{k=1}^n$ vectors with equal components.

Then $\mathrm{det}(A)$ is nonzero, and $1 + v^T A^{-1} u$ is nonzero because it is $$1 + t \sum_{i,j} A^{-1}_{ij} = 1 + t \sum_{i=1}^n (a_{ii} - t)^{-1}$$ which is positive.

Comment: In particular we have found the determinant $\Big(1 + t\sum_{i=1}^n (a_{ii} - t)^{-1}\Big) \prod_{i=1}^n (a_{ii} - t).$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A=D+tuu^T$, where $D=\operatorname{diag}(a_{11},a_{22},\ldots,a_{nn})-tI$ is a positive diagonal matrix and $u^T=(1,1,\ldots,1)$. If $Ax=0$, then $0=x^TAx=x^T\sqrt{D}\sqrt{D}x+tx^Tuu^Tx=\|\sqrt{D}x\|^2+t(u^Tx)^2$, where $\sqrt{D}$ is the entrywise square root of $D$. Since $t\ge0$, we must have $\|\sqrt{D}x\|=0$ and in turn $\sqrt{D}x=0$. As $\sqrt{D}$ is invertible, it follows that $x=0$. Therefore $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution, i.e. $A$ is invertible and its determinant is nonzero.